# How to test JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I have a builder that create a JPA Specification according to filters. How do I test the builder ? `assertEquals` method always return false when comparing Specifications...

I already try to call `Specification::toPredicate` method with mock args but the returned value is `null`. I would like to avoid loading the `entityManager`.

```java
Specification<MyClass> nullSpecification = Specification.where(null);
Specification<MyClass> nullSpecification2 = Specification.where(null);
assertEquals(nullSpecification, nullSpecification2);
```

I expected `assertEquals(nullSpecification, nullSpecification2)` to return true but the actual value is false. How can I compare JPA Specification ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see the following options.

1. Bite the bullet and create an integration test, i.e. create an `EntityManager` and run queries against an in memory database or Testcontainers.
2. Inspect the internals of the generated `Predicate` by passing in carefully configured mocks and then using type checking, reflection and knowledge of internals of your JPA provider to assert that you'll get the right predicate.

The problem with the 2nd approach is that it is very brittle and is likely to break although the `Specification` is actually fine.
I therefore would go with option 1 although I'd prefer a unit test as well.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will do both :)